# SSRS Charts Query and Data Series

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to this forum but Id like to ask about Charting in Reporting Services which I am completley new to too.

I want to create a chart data series that is called Months displaying the data April to March. However, the data in the tables and query is set us as follows not having a `monthname`; returns data fields; `Ref, Year, Month1datavalue, Month2datavalue, Month3datavalue.... Month12datavalue`.

Query as below:

```
SELECT     ChartData.Year, ChartData.Month1, ChartData.Month2, ChartData.Month3, ChartData.Month4, ChartData.Month5, ChartData.Month6, ChartData.Month7, 
                      ChartData.Month8, ChartData.Month9, ChartData.Month11, ChartData.Month10, ChartData.Month12, ChartData.SeriesName, ChartData.ColorName, ChartData.Style, 
                      Performance.ReferenceNo, Performance.ShortName, Performance.FullName, Performance.Description, Performance.Active, Performance.Deleted
FROM         ChartData INNER JOIN
                      Performance ON ChartData.PerformanceID = Performance.PerformanceID
WHERE     (ChartData.Year = 2015)
```

I create the chart but the `month1data` appears as a separate series to `month2data`. Ideally I would like the `month1data,month2data,month3data` fields to be as one series being able to show the month names in the horizontal axis title.

Any ideas for such as novice?

Thanks

Comment: can you post a picture of what it is looking like right now?

Comment: Share your query to help you pivoting the dataset and get the proper data arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query and your requeriments posted in the question, I recreated your scenario with sample data.

**Update:** I've updated the query to return the month of the year number. This let you put the name of the months in the x-axis.

Try this:

```
With pivot_cte as
(
SELECT 
    ChartData.[Year],ChartData.Month1, ChartData.Month2, ChartData.Month3, ChartData.Month4,
    ChartData.Month5, ChartData.Month6, ChartData.Month7, ChartData.Month8, ChartData.Month9,
    ChartData.Month11, ChartData.Month10, ChartData.Month12, ChartData.SeriesName,
    ChartData.ColorName, ChartData.Style, Performance.ReferenceNo, Performance.ShortName,
    Performance.FullName, Performance.Description, Performance.Active, Performance.Deleted
FROM 
    ChartData INNER JOIN Performance ON ChartData.PerformanceID = Performance.PerformanceID
WHERE
    (ChartData.Year = 2015)
)
select
    [Year],
    SeriesName, 
    ColorName,
    Style,
    ReferenceNo,
    ShortName,
    FullName,
    [Description],
    Active,
    Deleted,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) [Month], --New line added in UPDATE
    Value
from
    (select * from pivot_cte) p
UNPIVOT
    (Value FOR [Values] in
    (Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Month5,Month6,Month7,Month8,Month9,Month10,Month11,Month12)
    ) as unpivot_dt;
```

This will give you columns as rows and let you create only one data serie. Also it will return a `Month` column in order to put the name of the month on the x-axis.

Run the [updated](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3649/0) fiddle with data example only with demostration purposes and note the data structure required for your chart.

With the data exposed in the fiddle I created this chart. with `Value` field in the Serie and `Month` in Category Groups.

[image]

In the Category Gropus right click the `Month` field, go to `Category Groups properties` and put the following expression for the `Label`.

```
=Choose(Fields!Month.Value,
"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
)
```

[image]

This will preview the following chart.

[image]

If you want to show only **Apr** and **May** filter the dataset, right click on the dataset and go to properties, in the properties go to `filter` tab, and click add button.

[image]

In the expression `1` put this expression:

```
=CStr(Fields!Month.Value)
```

For the expression `2` put this one:

```
=Split("4,5",",")
```

Note I put `4` for `Apr` and `5` for `May`, so if you need to show `Oct`,`Nov` and `Dec` you should put `=Split("10,11,12",",")`

With the filter the chart will show `Apr` and `May`.

[image]

Let me know if this could help you.

Comment: Thank you alejandro a great help but one question how did you create the month values in the horizontal axis? 1~12? as the query does return the data in the correct arrangement but with no month labels as such.

Comment: Can I order and label this in the sql as Month1data value would equal Apr, Month2data value would equal May.

Comment: alejandro, great help, i may be back!

Comment: @wodz ,Hope this has help you, if your question has been cleared you can select my answer as correct by clicking on the correct symbol at the left side of my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks alejandro, is there anyway to reset the row number when the reference changes and when the series name changes.

Comment: @wodz, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)